# Clarifying google map (charging, versions)

Tags: google-maps

I am getting confused about Google Map.

I am writing a CMS website using `Ektron CMS`.

That CMS has a map function which in turn used google map.

Till last year, I can get an `API key` for the map and everything was fine.

But When I created a new website yesterday, I cannot find the page to get the key anymore.

After searching a while, I found out that I need to sign in and add the `services` to get the key.

Then I found out the `charging scheme` as it is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011553/google-maps-charging-costs-how-it-works-what-defines-a-click)
Then I also found out that Google Map V2 is deprecated.

Does it mean we can no longer use V2 ?

Can I just change `v=2` to `v=3` and everything will work fine?

What about charging scheme? If google really charges, will it be a lot?

Comment: Are you using Maps API for Flash?

Comment: According to Google, it was deprecated long back but apps depending on v2 will be working fine for now. Have you checked the official notice regarding the same?

Comment: @pansp : Yes, I know it will work fine. but will they work in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**switch from V2 to V3:**

You cannot use V2-code with the V3-library, you have to update your code, it's completely different.

**charging**:
usually the use of v3 is free of charge, as long as you didn't exceed the [limits](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/usage.html) and the map is accessible for everyone without any costs.

Answer (score 0):

According to Google, [API for Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html), Version 2 has been officially deprecated as of May 19, 2010 and they would be supporting it for 3 yrs which means your API key should be working fine unless you would have got a notice regarding the same.

This [link](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_4_4) shows Google's terms of service discontinuation. I guess you'll want to upgrade to v3 asap to keep your software up and running. :)